# how to make specific text in email message in bold using python

Tags: python-3.x, list, html-email

I am using Windows10 OS, Python 3.7.9 64-bit, I am send automated email in which the employee name alone must be in **Bold**, I tried the below code, but not getting proper output

```
e_name = "XXX"
msg = "Dear " + '\033[1m' + e_name + '\033[0m' + "\n\n"
```

Expected output:
Dear **XXX**

Actual Output:
[image: Bold]

In the terminal, it prints the bold text, but while receiving mail, I am getting like this. **Please help on this**

Also, I want to some items in the list with bullet points which are not manually printed using print statement, the values are in the list of in the dataframe, so I will be using for loop for iteration.

**How to print those with bullets (. dot) preceeding the each items.. This also will be the part of the email message.**

[image: list]

below is my code, inside for loop, where each item should be displayed with bullets and in bold text in the email.

```
message = row['employee_id'][i] + "  --  " + row['employee_name'][i] + "\n\n"
```

also tried simple_colors package,below is the code, even for this method, in the terminal, I am getting correct output, but in the email getting the same **Actual Output** shown above

```
from simple_colors import *
message = black(row['employee_id'][i] + "  --  " + row['employee_name'][i] + "\n\n", 'bold')
```

Comment: Are you not able to use HTML?

Comment: Not able to use HTML. Pls suggest any solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make bold text unless your application is able to use Markdown or similar. However, to emphasise anyway, you could simply add an asterisk or two, i.e. `**xxx**`

You can, however, include a bullet as text. The Unicode is U+2022 or you can copy this: • (see also https://unicode-table.com/en/2022/ or the white bullet https://unicode-table.com/en/25E6/).

Comment: Unicode for bullet worked fine, thanks for your help. But still I am unable to have bold text on sending automated emails.